# Reflection of genealogy trees

Tags: trees, genealogytree, genealogy

Is it possible to reflect around a vertical axis the structure of a genealogytree? Text should not be reflected. For example, in the tree below, the A column should be to the right, the "B's third" to the left of "B's second". The [documentation](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/genealogytree/genealogytree.pdf), page 284, shows some examples but I can't find the code to reproduce that.

I am not looking for a hack to make this minimal tree reflected, but something more general, like an option that would mirror the structure.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
\begin{genealogypicture}[
  ]
  child{
    g{Oldest}
    child{
      g{A}
      child{
        g{A's}
        child{
            g{A'ss}
            }
        }
    }
    child{
      g{B}
      c{B's first}
      c{B's second}
      c{B's third}
    }
}
\end{genealogypicture}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can find the source code of the manual on CTAN or https://github.com/T-F-S/genealogytree/tree/master/doc/latex/genealogytree (the .zip file). The examples you refer to are in the file `genealogytree.doc.autolayout.tex`. Looks like the reflected version is created by rewriting the structure of the tree though, not by some option passed to `\genealogytree`. That would lead me to think that no such option exists. I don't know how the package does the layout, so I can't say how hard it would be to implement something like it.

Comment: [The package author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/30617/thomas-f-sturm) visits here from time to time, so he might see your question. Making a feature request at https://github.com/T-F-S/genealogytree/issues could also be an option.